# PHP Pass By Reference Increases Memory Usage

Tags: php, memory, memory-management

When calling functions and passing in a large string I normally pass by reference. The intent is to keep PHP from passing by value a copy of the string, thus reducing memory usage.  However, I have noticed the opposite under certain circumstances.

In the below example, peak memory usage doubles when passing the string by reference into the function, at the is_string() call.

Code:

```
$buf = '';
report_memory(__LINE__);

$buf = file_get_contents('./20MB.pdf');
report_memory(__LINE__);

example($buf);
report_memory(__LINE__);

function example(& $str) {
    report_memory(__LINE__);
    is_string($str);
    report_memory(__LINE__);
}

function report_memory($line=0) {
    echo 'Line: ' . str_pad($line,3) . ' ';
    echo 'Mem: '  . str_pad(intval(memory_get_usage()/1024     ) . 'K',8) . ' ';
    echo 'Peak: ' . str_pad(intval(memory_get_peak_usage()/1024) . 'K',8) . ' ';
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Line: 2   Mem: 625K     Peak: 631K
Line: 5   Mem: 21058K   Peak: 21076K
Line: 11  Mem: 21058K   Peak: 21076K
Line: 13  Mem: 21058K   Peak: 41494K
Line: 8   Mem: 21058K   Peak: 41494K
```

Changing the function example() to remove the reference:

```
function example($str) {
    report_memory(__LINE__);
    is_string($str);
    report_memory(__LINE__);
}
```

Output:

```
Line: 2   Mem: 625K     Peak: 631K
Line: 5   Mem: 21058K   Peak: 21076K
Line: 11  Mem: 21058K   Peak: 21076K
Line: 13  Mem: 21058K   Peak: 21076K
Line: 8   Mem: 21058K   Peak: 21076K
```

This is what I would expect.  So then why the memory doubling with is_string() when the variable is a reference?

The environment is CentOS 6.6 running a stock PHP 5.3.3.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider raising this question as an issue at bugs.php.net where you're more likely to get a definitive answer from the PHP core development folks... while a few of them do frequent StackOverflow, and may see your questions, you're more likely to get an accurate answer by asking the people responsible for coding PHP Itself

Comment: And if you're assessing PHP at this level of detail, then using a tool like the [Vulcan Logic Dumper](http://pecl.php.net/package/vld), which analyses your code at op-code level, may give you some insight as to how PHP works "under the hood"

Comment: @Mark Baker: At the moment I am looking at this as an issue with my knowledge of how PHP works (Versus a PHP bug or implementation decision). Two good ideas though. Thanks!

Comment: Well as a way of learning how PHP works, reading the source is always useful (though difficult to trace at how arguments are passed to functions rather than simply looking at the code for the functions themselves), but the VLD is a really useful tool

Comment: This issue has been resolved as of PHP 7.2.24 (at most).

Answer (score 1):

Zend Engine uses a lazy-copy mechanism. Until the variable is modified it does not create a copy of the variable. PHP create a set of structures that it uses to maintain the reference that why it is actually “slower” to pass a variable by reference.

Comment: I understand the lazy-copy. That is not the issue. The question is: Why does passing be reference increase peak memory usage in this this instance, the call to is_string()?